# Two SWT tables fighting to grab space

Tags: layout, swt

I have two SWT tables wrapped in a `Group`, which has a `ScrolledComposite` to prevent browser scroll bars (and instead just scroll the table).

```java
table_sizing_toolInfo = new Table(grpCapacityReport, SWT.BORDER);
table_sizing_toolInfo.setData( RWT.FIXED_COLUMNS, Integer.valueOf(6));
table_sizing_toolInfo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

Both tables have `GridData` which grabs excess vertical space.

When rendering with no data the tables work as expected (both have grab excess, and so they split the view space).
Once data is populated into the tables, it **still** displays as expected, until switching Tabs (forcing redraw).

```java
table_sizing_dgrInfo.setRedraw(false);
table_sizing_toolInfo.setRedraw(false);
table_sizing_dgrInfo.removeAll();
table_sizing_toolInfo.removeAll();
while (table_sizing_dgrInfo.getColumnCount() > 6 ) {
  table_sizing_dgrInfo.getColumns()[6].dispose();
}
while (table_sizing_toolInfo.getColumnCount() > 6 ) {
  table_sizing_toolInfo.getColumns()[6].dispose();
}
renderSizingTableDynamic(scenarioMap.get(combo_sizing_ScenarioID.getText()));
table_sizing_toolInfo.setRedraw(true);
table_sizing_dgrInfo.setRedraw(true);
```

The bottom table holds more data than the top table and as more rows are added the bottom table swallows up the top table's space until it is just a single pixle tall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScrolledComposite` is unlikely to serve your needs here. If you want both tables to take the same height, then you should use a `Rowlayout` like this:

```java
parent.setLayout( new RowLayout( SWT.VERTICAL ) );
Table topTable = new Table( parent, ... );
Table bottomTable = new Table( parent, ... );
```

You could also use a `SashForm` as the parent of both tables. Thus letting the user drag the sash that separates the tables and decide how much height each table should take.

For further information, the article [Understanding SWT Layouts](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) provides an in-depth discussion of the SWT standard layouts. You can safely disregard the deprecation warning, the concepts discussed there are stil valid.

Comment: I did not want both tables to have the same height. The top table should fit the content, and the bottom table should grab excess vertical space. 

In this case an expanding gridlayout worked with `dgrInfoGD.minimumHeight = SWT.DEFAULT;`

The issue here is that the excess variable space is conditional to the browser window space(I do not have dynamic resize listener layouts...yet).

With that condition in mind, even though for my use the window space should always have enough room for both tables the `SashForm` is the most consistent for UX.